How to Install an Older Version of Magento PWA that Supports Magento 2.4.6?
I'm currently working on a project that uses Magento 2.4.6, and I need to install a compatible version of Magento PWA. However, I'm having trouble finding the right version that supports this specific Magento version.
Could someone guide me on how to:
Identify the correct version of Magento PWA that is compatible with Magento 2.4.6?
Install that version properly?
Thanks in advance!
I have tried downloading the pwa source code of 13.1.0 version but im facing this below issue:
ERROR in ./node_modules/@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/SavedPaymentsPage/savedPaymentsPage.module.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/SavedPaymentsPage/savedPaymentsPage.module.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError
(35:4) /var/www/html/pwamine/node_modules/@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/SavedPaymentsPage/savedPaymentsPage.module.css referenced class name "lg_grid-cols-[1fr" in composes not found

  33 | 
  34 |     /* TODO @TW: review (B7) */
> 35 |     composes: lg_grid-cols-[1fr,1fr,1fr] from global;
     |    ^
  36 | }
  37 | 

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
compile failed issue

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
